# Reference a range dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

I have this list
[image]

I want to first find familiyX and then go down to mum or dad side and then save the adresses listed below in the variable sTo.

```vb
Sub findAndStore()

    Dim EmailRng As Range, cl As Range
    Dim sTo As String, fam As String

    fam = "family2"

    Set EmailRng = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("D3:D" & Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("sheet2").Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each cl In EmailRng
        sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value
    Next

End Sub
```

The range is hardcoded. How can I make it dynamic based on that value fam holds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you actually need a code to do it ?

I would recommend to create a new sheet, where the data are fields by column and records per row, than create a pivot table and get the information you need.

However for sake of VBA training

```
Sub findAndStore(family_name As String)
    ' find the family column
    Dim family_column As Integer, mum_column As Integer, dad_column As Integer
    family_column = ActiveSheet.Range("1:1").Find(family_name).Column
    
    ' get values
    Dim collected_addresses As String
    Dim addresses_collection As Variant
    Set addresses_collection = New Collection
    
    For column_offset = 0 To 1 'mum and dad column
        
        current_row = 3 'start on a third row under dad/mum header
        Do
            cell_value = ActiveSheet.Cells(current_row, family_column + column_offset).Value
            current_row = current_row + 1 'move to next row
            If cell_value <> "" Then addresses_collection.Add cell_value
        Loop Until cell_value = ""
    
    Next column_offset ' next column
    
    For Each s In addresses_collection
        collected_addresses = collected_addresses & s & ";"
    Next s
    
    Debug.Print collected_addresses

End Sub
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your input prom! 
the thing is i want to either have the adress under mom or dad not both and i want the .find step to be based on whats stored in fam variable. This is just step one and step two creats an email but that step i got covered already.

Comment: The find part is based on the family_name parameter, just change it to your will or use a cell value if you like.

Comment: I used your code with a bit of my own touch and got it to work, thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. If it was of a help, mark me as an answer please.